# Error no chrome Binary with selenium want to use chrome driver to run selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

When I input the code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

I get the error:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-108802ed874c> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
     18 chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
---> 19 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
     20 chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
     21 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

System: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

I have tried a few different ways to get Chrome running through python but it just doesn't seem to budge. I either get a chrome binary error or installation error. Any solutions? It's a web scraping code.

Comment: should `chrome_options` given the line `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` and `chrome_options` is not defined anywhere else.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error says that its unable to find the chrome executable. I would first make sure that the path is correct.